# How to customize the facebook like button dynamically for each different page

Tags: facebook-like

i want the item name (in the page title) to post back to facebook...

```
   <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=rent.neighborrow.com/items/view/<?= $item["Item"]["item"];?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:; width:450px; height: 30px; text-align: center;margin-top: 10px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive if this is what you are asking, but I think you want to use the opengraph meta tags.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

```
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
</head>
```

Once a user clicks on the "like" button facebook makes a webservice call that scrapes the opengraph meta tags on your site to build a graph object. You want to set the "og:title".

Comment: that helps for the open graph- but i thnk there is a way to just get the page title in each post

Comment: open graph is where FB gets the text to use, you will need to run it through 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
to get it to recache